# Getting a " in has_table assert schema is not None Assertion Error" when using flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having an issue with an Assertion Error. I am trying to integrate a connection to a gcp mySQL instance using flask_sqlalchemy. I have successfully connected to the instance using the sqlalchemy package in another file called creat_db.py; however, when I try to integrate it into my flask_sqlalchemy implementation, I get an insertion error that says the assert schema is none. This is when I call db.create_all(). What would be the cause of this error?

I tried going to [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.engine.default.DefaultDialect.has_table) for documentation information but did not find a solution. I have also tried initializing my classes such as user and LoginForm. I am stuck on where to move forward or where to check.

Here is my code for main file.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError, DataRequired, EqualTo, Length
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import pandas as pd
import csv
#from model_subsystem import svm
from upload_to_model import Pre_Processing_data

#import create_db
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
import create_db

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

DB_HOST=os.getenv('DB_HOST')
DB_PASSWORD=os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
DB_USER=os.getenv('DB_USER')
DB_NAME=os.getenv('DB_NAME')
DB_PORT=os.getenv('DB_PORT')
PROJECT_ID=os.getenv('PROJECT_ID')
INSTANCE_NAME=os.getenv('INSTANCE_NAME')
print(type(DB_PORT))
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "service-account-key.json"))


app = Flask(__name__)


#MySQL DB
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="mysql+pymysql://"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"]={
    'creator': create_db.getconn, 
    'pool_size': 5,
    'max_overflow': 2,
    'pool_timeout': 30,
    'pool_recycle': 1800, }


#initialize db
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'signin'


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    results = db.relationship('Result', backref='poster')

    def __init__(self, id, email, username, password_hash, date_added):
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = password_hash
        self.date_added = date_added

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('Password is not a readable attribute!')
    
    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)






class Result(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    type_of_cancer = db.Column(db.String(50))
    model_type = db.Column(db.String(50))
    model_type_of_cancer = db.Column(db.String(50))
    outcome = db.Column(db.String(50))
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, id, uid, type_of_cancer, model_type, model_type_of_cancer, outcome, date_created):
        self.id = id
        self.uid = uid
        self.type_of_cancer = type_of_cancer
        self.model_type = model_type
        self.model_type_of_cancer = model_type_of_cancer
        self.outcome = outcome
        self.date_created = date_created




class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Email"})

    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})

    password_hash = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password_hash2', message='Passwords Must Match!')], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})

    password_hash2 = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Confirm Password"})

    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    # def validate_username(self, username):
    #     existing_user_username = User.query.filter_by(
    #         username=username.data).first()
    #     if existing_user_username:
    #         raise ValidationError(
    #             'Username already exists.')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})

    password_hash = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})

    submit = SubmitField("Submit")



@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/dashboard")
@login_required
def dashboard():
    id = current_user.id
    results = Result.query.order_by(Result.date_created)
    return render_template("dashboard.html", results=results, id=id)

@app.route("/input", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def input():
    return render_template("input.html")

@app.route('/resultpage/<int:id>')
@login_required
def resultpage(id):
    userid = current_user.id
    result = Result.query.get_or_404(id)
    return render_template('resultpage.html', result=result, userid=userid)



@app.route("/results", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.form['csvfile']
            type_of_cancer = request.form['type_of_cancer']
            model_type = request.form['model_type']
            model_type_of_cancer = request.form['model_type_of_cancer']

            results_numpy = Pre_Processing_data(f)
            results_str = 'empty'
            if model_type_of_cancer == 'Multiclass':
                if results_numpy == [0]:
                    results_str='Kidney - Not Cancerous'
                elif results_numpy == [1]:
                    results_str='Kidney - Cancerous'
                elif results_numpy == [2]:
                    results_str='Lung - Not Cancerous'
                elif results_numpy == [3]:
                    results_str='Lung - Cancerous'
                elif results_numpy == [4]:
                    results_str='Breast - Not Cancerous'
                elif results_numpy == [5]:
                    results_str='Breast - Cancerous'
            else:
                results_str='Model type not found'
            

#    class Result(db.Model, UserMixin):
#     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
#     uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
#     type_of_cancer = db.Column(db.String(50))
#     model_type = db.Column(db.String(50))
#     model_type_of_cancer = db.Column(db.String(50))
#     outcome = db.Column(db.String(50))
#     date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
            active_user = current_user.id
            #user = User(email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data, password_hash=hashed_password)
            result = Result(type_of_cancer=type_of_cancer, model_type=model_type, model_type_of_cancer=model_type_of_cancer, outcome=results_str, uid=active_user)
            db.session.add(result)
            db.session.commit()

            return render_template('results.html', model_type=model_type, type_of_cancer=type_of_cancer, results_str=results_str, model_type_of_cancer=model_type_of_cancer)



@app.route("/models")
def models():
    return render_template("models.html")

@app.route("/miRNA")
def miRNA():
    with open('example_data\CancerMIRNome.csv') as file:
        data = []
        csvfile = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csvfile:
            data.append(row)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return render_template("miRNA.html", data=data.to_html(header=False, index=False))

@app.route("/tutorial")
def tutorial():
    return render_template("tutorial.html")

@app.route("/signin", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            # Check the hash
            if check_password_hash(user.password_hash, form.password_hash.data):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                flash("Wrong Password")
        else:
            flash("Username not found")

    return render_template("signin.html", form=form)


@app.route("/signup", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is None:
            hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password_hash.data, "sha256")
            user = User(email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data, password_hash=hashed_password)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        form.email.data = ''
        form.username.data = ''
        form.password_hash.data = ''
        flash("Registeration successful! Please log in.")
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    return render_template("signup.html", form=form)


@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('Successfully logged out.')
    return redirect(url_for('signin'))


@app.route("/svmmulticlass")
def svmmulticlass():
    return render_template("svmmulticlass.html")

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Here is my create_db.py file

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Used for creating sql querys and connections
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Engine

# googles sql connector that uses Authorizes application with googles ADC
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import pymysql  # is a depenency of google.cloud.sql.connector

# used to load im enviroment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

host_cred=os.getenv('DB_HOST')
password_cred=os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
user_cred=os.getenv('DB_USER')
db_cred=os.getenv('DB_NAME')
INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=os.getenv('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "service-account-key.json"))

# Creates authenticated connector
def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:

    ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC
    with Connector() as connector:
            conn = connector.connect(
            "{INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}",
            "pymysql",
            user=user_cred,
            password=password_cred,
            charset='utf8',
        )
    return conn

# Connects to mysql via tcp socket
def connect_tcp_socket() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    # creates a engine object for connections
    engine: Engine = create_engine(
        "mysql+pymysql://",creator=getconn,#<db_user>:<db_pass>@<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds
        pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
    )
    return engine

# engine = connect_tcp_socket()

# # Shows database
# with engine.connect() as conn:
#     # returns a result.cursorresult object. Hence a list of Rows
#     database = conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text('CREATE DATABASE mirna'));
#     print("database created")
```

Here is my error and my stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\Desktop\college work\Spring2023\ED1\miRNACNet\miRNACnet.py", line 288, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 884, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 865, in _call_for_binds
    getattr(metadata, op_name)(bind=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 5576, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3220, in _run_ddl_visitor
    conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2427, in _run_ddl_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 670, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 903, in visit_metadata
    [t for t in tables if self._can_create_table(t)]
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 903, in <listcomp>
    [t for t in tables if self._can_create_table(t)]
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 868, in _can_create_table
    return not self.checkfirst or not self.dialect.has_table(
  File "<string>", line 2, in has_table
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 88, in cache
    return fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Owner.OWNER-PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py", line 2696, in has_table
    assert schema is not None
AssertionError
```

For anyone that can point me in the right the direction Thank you!

Comment: possibly because you didn't specify the database schema in `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`. Here are some docs on how it should look like [Connection URL Format](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/config/)

Comment: This is a crazy amount of code. It doesn't fit with Stack Overflow, see [mcve]